# Powershell : set download directory in chrome - selenium

Tags: powershell, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to change the default path for chrome downloads with selenium on powershell:

```
$savepath="path"
$ChromeOptions = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions
$chromePrefs=@{"download.default_directory" = $savepath}
$ChromeOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("prefs",$chromePrefs)
$driver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver($ChromeOptions)
```

**But here is the error I get** :

> Exception calling "AddAdditionalCapability" with "2" argument(s):
> "There is already an option for the prefs capability. Please use the
> instead. Parameter name: capabilityName"

Thanks !

Comment: Try `$ChromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", $savepath)`

Comment: Not working. No error but the download default directory doesn't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way that worked for me:

```
$myMap = @{}
$myMap.Add("default_directory", "c:\temp")
$myMap.Add("prompt_for_download", $true)

$ChromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download", $myMap)
```