# Powershell / Chrome Selenium - Forcing update of default download directory

Tags: powershell, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

I have been trying out some automation using Powershell and Selenium + Chrome, however I am struggling to be able to have the default download folder actually apply when Chrome is launched.

I have used [this as a guide to set the default download directory in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63667187/powershell-set-download-directory-in-chrome-selenium), and while it does boot launch Chrome with the directory set in "chrome://settings/?search=download", it isn't actually applied (unless you manually press the 'Change' button in settings, which defeats the point of automating it!) and still download to the default user downloads folder:

[Chrome settings after PS launch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBJmH.png)

```
#WebDriver.dll - C# 4.10 - .NET 4.8
#ChromeDriver - 97.0.4692.71 

$WorkingPath = 'C:\PSChromeSelenium'
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("$($workingPath)\WebDriver.dll")

$ChromeOptions = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions

$SavePath="C:\Temp"
$HashTable = @{}
$HashTable.Add("prompt_for_download", $true)
$HashTable.Add("default_directory", $SavePath)

$ChromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download", $HashTable)

$ChromeDriver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver($ChromeOptions)
```

[Downloading using 'Save / Save As' still opens to the default folder.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ooswf.png)

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi. Do you run this script as administrator? Try to set another driver, maybe `D:\Temp`?

Comment: @MaxDaroshchanka I have tried running the script as both a regular user and elevated as an administrator, as well as changing the drive used from C:\ to other types, but unfortunately it still doesn't properly use the set directory when trying to save.